# Insert a row using db migration - ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to ruby on rails. I need to insert a row into existing table using db migration, the table already have more than 200 rows of data and i need to insert one more row also.

I already created a migration file and it looks like below,

```
class AddNewGrowingMethodToEnumValues < ActiveRecord::Migration
  execute "INSERT INTO enum_values (enum_type, name, gdsn, created_at, updated_at) VALUES ('growing', 'Organic', '', now(), now())"
end
```

Is it correct/good?

Can any one help me to do migration to insert single row in correct/standard way.

Comment: populate data  is easy by doing `rake db:seed` using `db/seeds.rb` file

Comment: @RajarshiDas can you please provide us a sample.

Comment: yes http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data?view=asciicast this might help you http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data

Answer (score 3):

You can write as below:

```
class AddNewGrowingMethodToEnumValues < ActiveRecord::Migration
  enum_value = EnumValue.create(enum_type: 'growing', name: 'Organic', gdsn: '')
end
```

No need to write `created_at` and `updated_at`. `rails` will fill values for them when we run this `migration`.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't insert data into the database by using migrations. Migrations are used for creating the database structure.

If you have to insert prepared data you should use the `seeds.rb` file in the `db/` directory.

There is a short explanation in the file which describes how you should use it.

Happy coding :)

Comment: Hmmm, I'm going to have to go ahead and disagree with that. If you have tables that contain static reference values then it's entirely legitimate to maintain them with migrations. You might also use a migration to create a new table and populate it from existing data elsewhere, for example if you were normalising or denormalising existing data.

Comment: You might be right at some points. However if you have a database with **dynamic** statuses, otherwise you won't insert them into a database but rather use hardcoded statuses, then they shouldn't be in the migrations already. What if the app should be used differently later? Also the Rails Guides say in the headline of the [Migration Guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html): `Migrations are a feature of Active Record that allows you to evolve your database schema over time.`. So I think the cleanest way is to use `seeds` or a custom `import 'script'`.